# What is the best way to achieve push on CLDC devices?

Tags: java-me, midp-2.0, cldc

I would like to receive push messages from a server on most CLDC mobile phones while my application is running in background.

I did it already with SMS but it is costly so I'm thinking about another solution...

I know I can poll my server with HTTP requests.
Simple polling should be easy to implement. However, I don't have many updates to send (~5 per hours) but I need them to arrive on the device quickly (~1 minute).

Long polling is great but I think I will have to handle timeouts, disconnects...
While with socket I don't have the timeout problem, right?

So,

- Is there a simple solution/library to implement push ?
- Does keeping the connection alive has other problems : over-consumption of the battery, operator's firewall restriction... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need can be found in the [BlackBerry Push API documentation](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/pushapi.jsp).

Comment: Sorry, tag is misleading, I'm not using blackberry API. However this high level API looks great! No equivalent in standard j2me ?

Comment: No, the BlackBerry push infrastructure is, as far as I know, unique to BlackBerry devices. It is one of the great things about the platform.